# MVC Enum list bind in dropdown using angular JS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an MVC Enum List that I want to bind in a dropdown using angular method.
How could it possible?

```
public enum DefultBookType : byte
{
  Not Direct= 0,
  Individual = 1
}

public ActionResult Application(){
  ViewBag.BT = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DefultBookType)).ToList();
  return View();
}

@{
 var lstBT=  @ViewBag.BT
}
<select ng-model="Btype" ng-options="ctr as ctr.Name for ctr in lstBT track by ctr.Id">
   <option value="">select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as shown below code snippet.

Replace `enum` and `action` in `controller.cs` file:

```
public enum DefultBookType : byte
{
    NotDirect = 0,
    Individual = 1
}

public ActionResult Application()
{
    ViewData["BT"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Enum.GetValues(typeof(DefultBookType)), Formatting.Indented, new StringEnumConverter());
    return View();
}
```

Your `.cshtml` would be

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="key as val for (key, val) in @ViewData["BT"]">
   <option value="">select</option>
</select>
```

Drop down looks like as shown in screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Json.NET for convert a collection of objects into an array of objects, which then needs to be assigned in the m

```
@{
 var lstBT = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.BT);
}
```

And then you have to assign lstBT into the model of your controller for usage; you can't refer to lstBT directly, as lstBT is a server-side string, to be rendered to the client as client-side JavaScript array of JSON objects.

I'm not sure how a dynamic object works in serialization; if there are problems, you can switch ViewBag to ViewData.